# fflush(stdin) not working on Xcode on Mac

Tags: c, xcode, macos

This is the code which I'm trying to run on my Mac. In this the statement after `fflush` doesn't work. After `fflush` the compiler should stop and wait for the user input but it doesn't.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening or is there any other way to do it?

```
int main()
{
    int pos,neg,zero,num;
    char ans = 'y';

    pos=neg=zero=0;
    while(ans == 'y' || ans=='Y')
    {
        printf("\nEnter a number : ");
        scanf("%d",&num);

        if(num==0)
            zero++;

        if(num>0)
            pos++;

        if(num<0)
            neg++;

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nDo you want to continue?\n\n");
        scanf("%c",&ans);    
    } 
    printf("You entered %d positive numbers\n",pos);
    printf("You entered %d negative numbers\n",neg);
    printf("You entered %d zeros \n",zero);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour. read that many times here, so it must be true :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `fflush(stdin)` *is* undefined behavior according to the C standard. However, both POSIX and Windows define the behavior. Unfortunately, in both specifications the defined behavior is absolutely useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [***standard 7.21.5.2***](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2)

> **If stream points to an output stream** or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes
>   any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host
>   environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

You were having undefined behavior in your code. More clearly, `fflush` won't work. The most common way to do it would be something as shown below:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){}
```

Another solution would be to use (much easier for you but not robust)

```
scanf(" %c",&ans);
       ^^
```

This will make sure all white space is being consumed. This will solve one of the problem that may arise, but not all. (The others arise due to use of `scanf` and wrong input).

Side note

Also another way to get rid of this problem altogether would be to use `fgets` or similar to read one line and then use `strtol` or `strtod` to get the desired input parsed from the inputted line. `scanf` is extremely useful for formatted input. The scenario which you will have - it is better to use `fgets`, there are too many cases with `scanf` that you have to deal with otherwise.

For wrong input you need to flush the standard input so that you don't have to deal with them again in the next `scanf`. If you use `fgets` then you will get the input line from the stdin and then if you can parse it and the input is correct  - you go on processing it, else you discard the whole line and wait for the next `fgets` call.